# Getting added buttons to act as one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have two buttons which functions are to add and remove buttons. Also a third button which gets a user's Geolocation. How do make the buttons which were added to act as the third button? -meaning when buttons are added, automatically has the Geolocation function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   button{
     height:100px;
     width: 80px;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 5px 4px;
   }
  #mainButtons button{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    }
   </style>


 <div id="mainButtons">
 <button onclick="addButton()">Add Contact</button>
 <button onclick="removeButton()">Remove Contact</button>
</div>
</br>
<div id="que"></div>

<script>
var increment = 0;
function addButton(){
 $("#que").append($("<button id='btn"+(increment++)+"'>Send Location to: "+ (increment)+"</button>"));
}

function removeButton(){
  $("#btn"+(increment-1)).remove();
  increment--;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Send Location to: </button>

<p id="MyLocation"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("MyLocation");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
   }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can't you just add an onclick to your button? `$("#que").append($("<button id='btn"+(increment++)+"' onclick="getLocation">Send Location to: "+ (increment)+"</button>"));`

Comment: I'm not that smart haha just starting in learning html/java. will give this a try

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java, and in fact I've deleted your Java question tag. Please look up the difference between Java and Javascript for future reference.

Comment: will do. thank you for yor help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this done by passing the element to `getLocation`. Working example in [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/siqamuduge/1/edit?js,output).

```
var increment = 0;
function addButton(){
  var id = 'btn' + (increment++);
  var que = $("#que");
  var el = $("<button id='"+id+"'>Click for location</button>");
  que.append(el);
  clickHandler(el);
}

function removeButton(){
  if (increment >= 0) {
    $("#btn"+(increment-1)).remove();
    increment--;
  }
}

function clickHandler(el) {
  el.click(function() {
    getLocation(el);
  });
}

function getLocation(el) {
  el.html("Loading....");
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { showPosition(el, position); });
  } else { 
    el.html("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(el, position) {
  el.html("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot thank you. but can the location be displayed only if "Loading..." button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Add a `click` handler to your element. I've added another example here on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/siqamuduge/1/edit?js,output).

Comment: when I clicked on it, loaction wasn't displayed

Comment: Dude you're amazing (y) Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add a button after binding events?

```
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
function addButton(){
 var aa = $("<button id='btn"+(increment++)+"'>Send Location to: "+ (increment)+"</button>")
 $("#que").append(aa);
 $(aa).click(showPosition);
}
```

Comment: supposedly when I click the "add contact" button it should be the "send location to:" button which displays the user's current location when it is clicked without disturbing the "remove button" function